# Cannot declare variable for mysql (whmcs)

Tags: php, mysql, database, whmcs

I have made a variable in Javascript and used it in PHP.

First I declared my variable `firstname` like this:

```
{literal}
  <script>
    var fornavn = "{/literal}{$clientsdetails.firstname}{literal}";
  </script>
{/literal}
```

then I declared it in PHP like this:

```
$fornavn = "<script> document.write(fornavn) </script>";
```

It works fine when I print it out it gives me the logged in `username`, but when I place it inside a table in my database, it gives me this:

```
<script> document.write(fornavn) </script>
```

Even if I declare the variable like this:

```
{literal}
  <script>
    var fornavn = "something";
  </script>
{/literal}
```

it does the same thing.

Hope someone knows how I can do it right and maybe how I can do it in another way.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is it encoding the script tag brackets to be &lt; and &gt;?  I'm not sure what you mean by placing inside your database, unless you are literally putting that code into a field in your database, and fetching it it may encode it as html entities instead of rendering it as intended.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script>
var fornavn = "{ldelim}$clientsdetails.firstname{rdelim}";
</script>
```